# Disregard from part in import loop

Tags: loops, import, stata

I have several data files that I want to import into Stata with 4 different loops in the following way

```
import delimited "path\`x´name`i´`j´`k´.T0653248.csv clear"
```

where x is a foreach loop over different markets and i,j, k are forvalues loops over year, month and days. My problem is that the last part, which always starts with a .T, is a random sequence not following any particular order or pattern.

I want to import all data files with 4 loops in this way while disregarding the last part, is this possible? (Or how can I remove it?) The other option is to manually delete this part from each data file but this is very tedious since I have several hundreds of data files.

Edit:

The code I'm trying to run is the following, where the user can change the loop settings depending on the data horizon of interest

```
foreach x in CO CR EQ FX IR {       // loop over market
    forvalues i = 2022/2022 {       // loop over year
        forvalues j = 9/9 {         // loop over month
            forvalues k = 23/23 {   // loop over day
            
                
                import delimited "path\ETD_`x'_Trade_State_Report`i'0`j'`k'.csv", varnames(3) clear

some data commands
}
}
}
}
```

The problem is, as stated above, that each data file has a unique number sequence at the end of the name which I cannot loop over. If I remove this part manually it works as intended. However, it's very tedious since I have several hundreds of data files which will grow over time.

UPDATE: I have so far tried the following but it doesn't import the data and no error message is shown

```
clear all
set more off, permanently


local path "path"

local files : dir "`path'" files "*.csv"

foreach file of local files {
    
    foreach x in CO CR EQ FX IR {
        forvalues i = 22/22 {
            forvalues j = 10/10 {
                forvalues k = 31/31 {
                
                if strpos("`file'", "ETD_`x'_Trade_State_Report.D`i'`j'`k'" ) {
                
                import delimited "`path'/`file'", varnames(3) clear
                                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax you cite is doomed to failure as a backslash before a local macro reference won't work and your punctuation for local macros is wrong. But it seems that you think your syntax is fine except for looping over filenames. See `help macro` -- under macro functions -- for the `dir` syntax to put filenames in a local macro.

Comment: Do you want to import all files in that folder? Or are your loops a way to filter which files you want to import?

Comment: Filter, since over time you can change the loop over which time intervals you want the data. I'm using daily data files so the folder will grow over time

Comment: Backslash does work.

Comment: Backslashes usually works in a file path, yes. However, if it comes immediately before a ` it tells Stata to not read that as a local reference. Google "escape characters" for general explanation of this.

Comment: You are combining two syntaxes in `foreach x of local in CO CR EQ FX IR {`. Either change this to `foreach x in CO CR EQ FX IR {` or put `CO CR EQ FX IR` in a local. I suggest the latter as you then can make that list long without making the `foreach` row convoluted.

Comment: That solves the error, but the data is not imported ...

Comment: You are looking for files that contain 221031 in their names, and not finding any, as your `i j k` loops are loops over constants.  Is that surprising?

Comment: I solved it by replacing strpos() with fileexists() command instead. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that use `macro dir` and filters filenames on only the years, months, and days you list in the locals with the same name in case you only need some of the files in that folder.

An unsolicited advice from me is to call your loop locals after what they represents. It makes your code much more readable.

```
    * Set a path to folder with the files
    local path "path/to/files"
    
    *List all .csv files in the folder
    local files : dir "`path'" files "*.csv" 
    
    * Loop over all the files
    foreach file of local files {

      * Loop over all parts of the file name you want to filter on - if
      * you want all files in the folder, then just remove these loops,
      * and the if-condition
      foreach x of local something {
        foreach year of local years {
          foreach month of local months {
            foreach day of local days {
                
                * Test if "`x´name`year´`month´`day´" is part of filename
                if strpos("`file'", "`x´name`year´`month´`day´") {
                    import delimited "`path'/`file'", clear
                    // Do something with the data
                }
            
            }      
          }      
        }  
      }
    }
```

Apologies from any bug since I do not have these files to test on. But you should get the logic and be able to solve.

Comment: I updated my code in the initial post if I was unclear.

Comment: Seems as if my solution would work then. Does it not work?

Comment: I tried the following which give some error

```
 foreach file of local files {
 
 foreach x of local in CO CR EQ FX IR {
  forvalues i of local = 22/22 {
   forvalues j of local = 10/10 {
    forvalues k of local = 31/31 {
    
    if strpos("`file'", "ETD_`x'_Trade_State_Report.D`i'`j'`k'" )
    
    import delimited "`path'/`file'", varnames(3) clear
     
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: you need to include the error message for it to be possible to help you

Comment: I'm runing:
"local path "path\DTCC"

local files : dir "`path'" files "*.csv"

foreach file of local files {
 
 foreach x of local in CO CR EQ FX IR {
  forvalues i = 22/22 {
   forvalues j = 10/10 {
    forvalues k = 31/31 {
    
    if strpos("`file'", "ETD_`x'_Trade_State_Report.D`i'`j'`k'" ) {
    
    import delimited "`path'/`file'", varnames(3) clear
    
    save "somepath\test.dta"
    
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}"
and get the message: "
{ required
r(100);
"

Comment: perhaps update your original question with an "I have so far tried this" section at the bottom to make this more readable