# Skip non existent data files in import loop

Tags: loops, import, stata

I have daily data files over weekdays (thus there is a gap during weekends, month's end etc) that I'm trying to import through several loops in Stata. I want to skip if the file is non existent and thus proceed to the next one. I've tried the -capture- command without success with the following code, I'm getting the error message "no variables defined
r(111);"

```
forvalues i = 2023/2023 {       // loop over year
    forvalues j = 2/3 {         // loop over month
        forvalues k = 1/28 {    // loop over day
            forvalues l = 1/2 { // loop over number
                
                if `k' < 10 {
                 
                capture import delimited "path/RA0041_TS_`i'0`j'0`k'_`l'.csv", varnames(2) clear
                }
                else {
                    
                capure import delimited "path/RA0041_TS_`i'0`j'`k'_`l'.csv", varnames(2) clear
                    
                }
                
                
                save "path/RA_TS_`i'`j'`k'_`l'.dta", replace
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should (1) cross-reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835860/disregard-from-part-in-import-loop (2) thank @TheIceBear for help and accept their answer, because you're using it here.

Comment: But it doesn't work:(

Comment: Cross-referencing is minimal courtesy here.

Comment: Not quite: it's your modification of the answer code that doesn't' work.

Comment: I solved it by adding "if fileexists()" in the if command. Thx anyway.

Comment: As you have a solution, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution where I added the fileexists() command in the if statement

```
forvalues i = 2023/2023 {       // loop over year
    forvalues j = 2/3 {         // loop over month
        forvalues k = 1/28 {    // loop over day
            forvalues l = 1/2 { // loop over number
                
                if (`k' < 10 & fileexists("path/RA0041_TS_`i'0`j'0`k'_`l'.csv")) {
                 
                capture import delimited "path/RA0041_TS_`i'0`j'0`k'_`l'.csv", varnames(2) clear
                }

                else if fileexists("path/RA0041_TS_`i'0`j'0`k'_`l'.csv") {
                    
                capure import delimited "path/RA0041_TS_`i'0`j'`k'_`l'.csv", varnames(2) clear
                    
                }
                
                
                save "path/RA_TS_`i'`j'`k'_`l'.dta", replace
            }
        }
    }
}
```